# ColdFusion 11 throws a 500 error on only one directory

Tags: windows, coldfusion, windows-server-2012, coldfusion-11

I'm running CF11 on a Windows 2012 R2 server. The site (migrated from windows 2003 running CF9) essentially runs great with the exception of 1 directory that I'm getting a 500 error. When I run www.site.com/test/index.html it shows the page, but www.site.com/test/index.cfm throws the 500 error. I removed the application.cfc and index.cfm has 4 characters... "test" and it throws the error.

I can find nothing unusual about the directory in IIS (8.5) not anything unusual in CF Admin.

I'm 100% perplexed! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the www.site.com/test/index.cfm showing any content or is it just blank and without any whitespace in the source?

Comment: Viewing source it shows:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head> 
 <title>ACIS</title>

Comment: If there is an Application.cfc with an `onError` method in it, I'd comment that temporarily out, because it could suppress ColdFusion's error output. Did you already have a look at CF's exception.log?

Did you already search for the template with this doctype and title in your cfm-files? Focus on the lines right below the `<title>`-tag. Maybe execution stops there because of an ColdFusion-error. Without any further information about your app it's all just a guess.

Comment: I appreciate you feedback. I've removed the application CFC entirely from the directory and the CFM template does nothing... it is four letters... "test". Even when I run a blank CFM template, it throws the error. I've never seen anything like it. The entire site is working well and fast except this directory!

Comment: Do you have any URL rewrite rules set in IIS? I'd have a look at these as well.

Comment: I found the issue. My bad.. I should have been clear that it was www.site.com/API/. We don't use REST components so I commented the following out of the web.xml file and restarted CF and it works fine:

<servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_16">
    <servlet-name>CFRestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. I should have been clear that it was `www.site.com/API/`. We don't use REST components so I commented the following out of the web.xml file and restarted CF and it works fine:

```
 <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_16">
   <servlet-name>CFRestServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12925601)

Comment: @Vini.g.fer - The above *is* an answer :-) The asker found the solution to their own question and are posting the solution for others.